# How to call javascript function when select dropdown value changes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a select component populated with options.  When I select one of them I want to call a javascript function.  The onchange event is not firing.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is the html that populates the select option list.  It works.

```
<select name="state" onchange="loadCounties()" id="state">
    <option value=''>Select one</option>
    <?php
        $states = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT ID,Name FROM State ORDER BY Name");
        while ($row = $states->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ($row['ID'] == $stateId) {
                echo "<option selected value=" . $row['ID'] . ">" . $row['Name'] . "</option>";
            } else {
                echo "<option value='" . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $row['Name'] . "</option>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

But when I select a value, the javascript function loadCounties() does not get called and no errors are shown in the console.

Here is the javascript function loadCounties()

```
function loadCounties() {
    var stateId = form.state.options[form.state.options.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log("stateId="+stateId);
}
```

I have also tried adding a change event using jquery like so:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('#state').on('change',function(){ alert('changed!!'); })
    }
);
```

But it doesn't fire either.  Suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors in the console, because the function works fine if you rip out all the php

Comment: No errors at all in the console.  Why would having php do the populating have anything to do with it?

Comment: I'm just saying since we can't see any data coming in ( and html being generated ), basic html with the JS you have works fine https://jsfiddle.net/e47nw91o/ , so unless you have another ID on the page with the same ID ( which will negate anything after the first one ) there isnt any bad code here

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle Keith.  I see it does work there.  I double-checked to make sure there is no other id="state" and there isn't.  Frustrating trying to debug with no error messages!

Comment: Try $(document).on('change', '#state', function(){ alert('this'); });

Comment: Same result.  I'll try to simplify the code down to the bare minimum until it works, then add stuff back in a little at a time until it breaks.

Comment: Please add the full page code, the code you mentioned, and code which other mentioned must work. so please update the question to have a look at the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems I was having was I was making changes and uploading using Filezilla but didn't realize the code was not being uploaded.  I closed Filezilla and reopened it.  Then it wanted me to upgrade it, so I did.  Then the transfers started working again.

What finally worked for me was putting the function loadCounties() into the script area, outside of the $(document).ready( function, like this:

```
function loadCounties() {
    var stateId = $('#state').val();
    console.log("stateId=" + stateId);
}
```

The function is called in the select component's onchange event, like this:

```
<select name="state" onchange="loadCounties()" id="state">
```

When I put it inside the document.ready function, I would get error "function loadCounties() is not defined".

Answer (score -1):

```
    $("#state").change(function () {
        var id =  $(this).val();

        //Javascript Function goes here what you want according to your requirement
    });
```

remove function from document ready